# Escalar Imagen en Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Tengo un canvas de 800x400, estoy pintando sobre ella una imágenes de dimensiones muy pequeña y pixeladas (5x5, 10x5, 7x5, 5x7, etc). Al mandarlas al canvas haciendo escalados de [2, 2], [4, 4] etc. No se hace de forma lineal y no conserva la claridad de los pixeles. ¿Cómo se puede lograr esto?

```js
var imagen = document.getElementById("img");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.drawImage(imagen, 10, 10);
ctx.scale(8,8);
ctx.drawImage(imagen, 10, 10);
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 5px solid black;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://minecraft-statistic.net/face/JRMUS.png" hidden >
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400" ></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo reproducible de lo que tienes hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto necesitas desactivar el `imageSmoothingEnabled` porque por defecto el canvas prueba alisar y suavizar las imágenes.

```js
var imagen = document.getElementById("img");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

ctx.drawImage(imagen, 10, 10);
ctx.scale(8,8);
ctx.drawImage(imagen, 10, 10);
```

```css
canvas{
 border: 5px solid black;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="400" >
<img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAsUlEQVQYlX2MMQrCQBBFX2JYNGC8gJ1EGzshh9ATpPIKIrYewEbE0i5FsLOztkxlFRsL8QzZhUQXJRZLtnRgmD/Dm+dMQ7fmT7lNOB62djYN4ExDt5ZvA50Tc5zNl3Z3AdIs5xFHVvuII9IsN4bisqvRbQBu9ysA49HEkOKFp8sC4RlgOOhTSWVNuizwKqkgAOH32OxPAKxXfXRZUEmF80wWdUt4dIIuwu/Zz0oqvvrDD0I/QTF2N0bTAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
</canvas>
```